# How to copy a file to 50 different folders?

Tags: batch-file

I need to copy a file and paste it inside "resources" folder that reside in 50 different folders with different names.

Using auto hot key is one option but i don't want to use that. can we use batch script to extract directory structure and paste into a folder with same title.

```
for  /D  %%a  in ("c:\Class 1\*.*") do xcopy  /y  /d  c:\test\work.txt "%%a\"
```

Using this script is another option but here i have to manually enter directory of destination each time. Is there any possibility to automate this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /ad /b /s ^| findstr /eir "\\resources"') do xcopy  /ydi c:\test\work.txt "%%~a"
```

code for Vista:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /ad /b /s ^| findstr /eir "\\\\resources"') do xcopy  /ydi c:\test\work.txt "%%~a"
```

Comment: need to copy folders as well. files work fine bit folders wont copy

Comment: add `s`  to the xcopy option string.

Answer (score -1):

You can launch the batch file in the folder you are processing.

```
for /D %%a in (*) do copy /y "c:\test\work.txt" "%%a\"
```